# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to [MyClass]

Tags: java, client-server, classcastexception, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am currently implementing a search functionlity where a string the user has entered is sent to the server which looks through the database and sends all the users whose username matches the given string back to the client. For transfering I use a custom class `Message` which contains a String that contains the action to be performed (irrelevant here) and an Object which is the actual message. In this case this would be an `ArrayList<User>`. I use the `writeObject()` method from `ObjectOutputStream` and the `readObject()` from `ObjectInputStream` to transfer data. After receiving the data I cast the Object to a Message object and this is where I get the exception. Note: casting to Message works fine at any other point in the code but here it throws an Exception.

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to gruber.common.Message
    at gruber.client.controller.ChatRoomController.lambda$searchForUser$2(ChatRoomController.java:105)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Client side:

```
 private void searchForUser(){
        try {
                oos.writeObject(new Message("SEARCH", searchfield.getText()));
                oos.flush();

                Message results = (Message)ois.readObject();

                ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList<User>)results.getMsg();
                for(User u: users) {
                    System.out.println(u.getUsername());
                }
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Server side:

```
 private void search() throws SQLException, IOException {
    Message client_msg = (Message) client.getOis().readObject();
    String searchParam = client_msg.getMsg();
        PreparedStatement searchUsers = con.prepareStatement("SELECT username, image from chatuser where username like ?");
        searchUsers.setString(1, searchParam);
        ResultSet results = searchUsers.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        while (results.next()) {
            users.add(new User(results.getString(1), results.getBytes(2)));
        }

        client.getOos().writeObject(new Message("SEARCH", users));
        client.getOos().flush();
    }
```

The message class (if relevant):

```
package gruber.common;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable {
    private String action;
    private Object msg;

    public Message(String action, Object msg) {
        this.action = action;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public Object getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(Object msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this exception stack on server or on client? Is `User` serializable?

Comment: The exception stack is client side and yes User is serializeable.

Answer (score 0):

If a class implements serializable, it should define an attribute serialVersionUID with a value you can freely define.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

If You don't define serialVersionUID it will be generated by java and can differ on different JVM's with a consequence that object cannot be interchanged between these JVM's.

Since You are speaking about client and server I assume that JVM's can be different on client and server. 
Your Message class implements Serializable but don't have serialVersionUID defined. Try to add this attribute. The same is valid for your user object.

Comment: This did not change anything.

Comment: Fot troubleshooting purposes leave the cast away.  Change the line 
    `Message results = (Message)ois.readObject();`
to 
    `Object results = ois.readObject();`
comment out code lines, which will not compile then set a breakpoint just behind this line and inspect the object results in debugger. Probalby through the content of the results object you will get a clue what is going wrong.

Comment: I tried this an the debugger told me that it did recognice that it was a Message object however for some reason it is still an ObjectStreamClass object. The weird thig is I also checked with the debugger on what happens at other points in the code when I save the oupt of readObject into an Object variable and cast it to Message and at every other point in the code this works completely fine because the streaam regocnizes it as a Message object and treats it as such.

Comment: Actually if I'm allowed to suggest you something, then java serialized objects are not the best choice for an interchange format. With this interface you could never replace your impelementation (client oder server side) with something else than java. If you would use json insead, then your server oder client can be anything. And marshaling an java object to json and unmarshaling it back to java object isn't really complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Actually I just foun the error in my programm. It is really specific to my program. I had two consecutive threads running which which both called ois.readObject(); I now placed it in the thread that is actually responsible for handling server responses and not in my drawing thread which I did before, stupid I know. It works just fine now but thank you for your help!